# Get the value of RadNumericTextBox in JavaScript or jQuery in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, telerik

I have a `RadNumericTextBox` in a `DetailsView`on a `ASP.Net` Web Page. I am trying to access this in JavaScript (jQuery). I have successfully got the `RadNumericTextBox` as a variable in javaScript and when I inspect the page this variable contains all the properties including the value of the `RNTB`.
However I get undefined for the result of `get_value()`. That is according to the literature for Telerik the right way to get the value. I have also tried val, value, and Text. None of them work.

Here is the `javaScript (jQuery)` I am using

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
    function addZerosToBSB(sender) {
        var BSB = $("#ctl00_XXXXXX_XXXXXXXWizard_XXXXXX_BSB");
        alert(BSB.value);//undefined
        alert(BSB.val); 
        alert(BSB.get_value()); // this is what telerik literature says to do but it is undefined
......
```

Here is the `DetailsView`

```
<asp:DetailsView runat="server" ID="XXXXXXXXXX" DataSourceID="XXXXXXX" Width="100%" DefaultMode="Edit" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="XXXXXXXXXX">
                    <FieldHeaderStyle Width="30%"></FieldHeaderStyle>
                    <Fields>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="BSB">                                
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <telerik:RadNumericTextBox runat="server" ID="BSB"  NumberFormat-GroupSeparator="" NumberFormat-DecimalDigits="0"  Text='<%# (Eval("BSB") %>' ></telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
.........
```

I have tried BSB.text in the javaScript and this is what it returns

```
ƒ (a){return S(this,function(a){return void 0===a? 
r.text(this):this.empty().each(function() 
{1!==this.nodeType&&11!==this.nodeType&&9!==this.nodeType|| 
(this.textContent=a)})},null,a,arguments.length)}
```

My question is how can I get the value of the `RadNumericTextBox` in `javaScript` and then how can I set it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery you have to use `BSB.val()`